# I want to run rdf from Oracle apex with two parameters

Tags: oracle-apex, oraclereports

Please help. I can't generate the proper url to call rdf using 2 parameters. When i hard code the values it runs successfully but when i put parameters it returns invalid value

Comment: Could you add any more information? Screenshots or snippets? Thanks!

Comment: to embed the value of an item use &YOUR_ITEM_NAME. & at first and dot at the end e.g. https://abc.parameter1=&ITEM_1._parameter2=&ITEM_2.